# Notify another thread when ServerSocket blocks on accept()

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency

I've got a pair of threads running a `Socket` and `ServerSocket`:

```
runThreadA() {
     // Connects to B, or fails if B is not yet accepting
     socket.connect();
}

runThreadB() {
    // Blocks until another thread connects
    serverSocket.accept();
}
```

Is there a way I can guarantee that `B` calls `accept()` and blocks before `A` calls `connect()`?

Comment: Do you really want to have 2 threads in the same JVM connecting to each other using a socket?  You might want to look into `BlockingQueue` to share data between threads.

Comment: I couldn't see a way around it. I'm using an SSL socket and a plain socket in loopback configuration so I can get the raw SSL stream and send it over a third socket. It's not exactly elegant, but those are the constraints...

Comment: Keep in mind that the OS will happily accept the incoming connection before your code calls accept(). `A` will do a successful connection even if you never call accept() at all. What are you actually trying to solve ? Perhaps you only need to synchronize thread A with thread B as it creates the socket instead.

Comment: @nos this was my assumption as well, but when I tried `socket.connect(SocketAddress)` with an arbitrary IP address it failed with `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: Err, start the accepting thread before starting the connecting thread?

Comment: @EJP That doesn't work because there's no guarantee the threads will execute in that order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeap, set a reasonable timeout

```
 runThreadA() {
    Socket s = new Socket()
    s.connect(endPoint, REASONABLE_TIMEOUT )
 }
```

That way, the thread A will attempt to connect but it will wait a REASONABLE amount of time before giving up.

*Update*

Another approach would be to have the second thread re-try for the same amount of REASONABLE time.

```
runThreadA() {
    maxTimeout = currentTime() + REASONABLE_TIMEOUT
    while ( currentTime() < maxTimeout ) { 
       socket.connect()
       if ( isConnected( socket ) ) { 
           break;
       }
       Thread.currentThread.sleep( A_WHILE )
    }
    if ( ! isConnected( socket ) ) { 
        .... too bad, we can't work this way
        exit();
    } 
    continue with the work here...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm working with a socket implementation that doesn't support timeouts.

Comment: ...Wait, apparently one of the sockets I'm using does in fact support timeouts. Thanks, that looks like it'll work for this case, but is there a more general solution to the threading problem?

Comment: Yes you can loop instead, the problem is you can't rely on how long would it take the server to start serving and accept connections. The easiest is wait an retry ( actually with an smaller timeout )

Comment: No. There already is a reasonable timeout. THe default is around 60 seconds. And it only applies when there is no response. If the host actively rejects the connection with an RST because nothing is listening at the port, as is the case here, the connection failure is immediate and the timeout does not apply. -1

Answer (score 1):

Check [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which can help you make the threads to wait each other, they might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think either of those are applicable here because I don't have access to the lock `accept()` is using.

Answer (score 1):

Code properly. If connect() fails, log the issue, wait a backoff time, and then retry, unless really too much time has passed. Even if the server is listening, connect() may fail for other reasons you and me might not be aware of (e.g. a layer somewhere in the network API has a full buffer). That's why `IOException` is a controlled exception, and the Java compiler expects you to explicitly handle it: `IOException`s may happen, but this is not a programming error.

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);

for (int waitTime = 10; waitTime < 10000; waitTime *= 2) {
    try {
        socket.connect();
    } catch (ConnectException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING,
                "Connection failed, retrying in " + waitTime + " ms...", ex);
        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected IO Exception", ex);
    }
}
```

Even if you used some synchronization primitives, like a barrier or a signaling, the server thread would always signal **before** listen() actually comes into effect. So, there would still be the possibility of bad thread interleavings.